# How to get list of visible columns of data bound grid of syncfusion?

Tags: c#, syncfusion

I am developing a windows application using c# and I am using data bound grid of syncfusion controls. What I want is the list of of all columns with their properties like visible, read only and enable

Comment: tumhi kay prayatna kelat bhau?

Comment: I used this: GridVisibleColumnDescriptorCollection visibleColumns = ggc.TableDescriptor.VisibleColumns; But by this code i can only see whether column is present or not

Answer (score 2):

If you are using GridDatsBound Grid , then you can get the column collection using the following code:

```
GridBoundColumnsCollection gc = this.gridDataBoundGrid1.Binder.InternalColumns
```

The other properties like Hidden, ReadOnly and Enabled can be accessed by using the following codes:

```
bool hidden, readalone , enabled;
for (int i = 0; i < gc.Count; i++)
{
    hidden = gc[i].Hidden;
    readalone = gc[i].ReadOnly;
    enable = gc[i].StyleInfo.Enabled;
}
```

I hope this will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this if you are using GridDataControl.

```
var hiddencolumns = grid.VisibleColumns.Select(col => col.IsHidden == true);
```